TV show which re-enacted large scale historical battles
This show is recent enough, the last 5 years maybe.
Was on the BBC I believe.
Using software which very much resembled Total War gameplay, each week contestants would re-enact historical battles and see if different tactics could produce a different outcome.
The battles were all medieval and earlier I think, all sword and shield stuff.
Anyone know what I'm talking about?

@Richard And Decisive Battles apparently uses the same engine, but I think it's more like a documentary (just a host and talking heads).

Sounds like Time Commanders from 2003 that ran on BBC for 2 seasons.

Each week four contestants come together as a team to recreate a historical battle via computer simulator. With two of the group playing generals with an overview of the battlefield, the other two play Lieutenants who are more in touch with the progress of the battle. When they lose or win, two military historians take them through on the simulator what actually happened in the real battle.

They usually dealt with famous ancient battles. Here's a clip from season 2:



BTW, it resembles Total War for the simple fact that they used their engine. ;)
